# Home value - relocating laundry to basement?

Tags: renovation

I would like to turn our first floor laundry room to a powder room and relocate the laundry room to basement. Is this a good idea to improve home value?

Comment: This may be more of an opinion type of question. I loved the multi story home I had that had a laundry shoot on both the upper levels. Older folks may not like the laundry downstairs but adding a extra bath is usually a good idea in my opinion. Using a small amount of space to make a laundry drop can be a real plus, the wife loved it I ended up making a small enclosed area to catch the dirty clothes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the resale value of a project. Please see https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/819/are-resale-worth-questions-ok-or-not/820#820 for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Adding bathrooms is, superficially at least, a good way to improve the appearance of real estate listings. This can bring more interest. Whether you can expect to achieve a higher sale price as a result is unclear. Main floor laundry is also a desirable feature.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I do not think so - you are talking about taking laundry up and down stairs . But this is also a preference a younger buyer may not give it a whip of a thought. An older buyer will not like the haul. Make the basement a entertainment room of sorts and you are probably better off.

Comment: Depending on the size of your powder room and the layout of the sink and toilet, you may be able to stack a washer and dryer, add a very small sink and have the room do double duty.